# How to create an Object of List<Integer> type

Tags: java, generics, static

I am having trouble creating and using objects to type `List<Integer>`. When I run the following code, I get a `NullPointerException` because the *Object isn't initialized*.

```
import java.util.List;

public class RBTree {

    public static class Tree {
        public List<Integer> parent;
        public List<Integer> right;
        public List<Integer> left;
        public List<Integer> data;
        public List<Boolean> black;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Tree rb =new Tree();                
        rb.data.add(-1);
        rb.left.add(-1);
        rb.right.add(-1);
        rb.parent.add(-1);
        rb.black.add(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

The compiler also gives me errors unless I add `static` to the `public static class Tree` line, but I don't want `Tree` to be `static` i.e. immutable.  I need to be able to use a Tree more-or-less like a `struct` in C.

Comment: The keyword `static` has nothing to do with immutability!

Comment: "this feels like I am missing something very basic" - yes, you are. Declaring the reference name and type does not allocate any memory.

Comment: Read through some Java tutorials, and you'll save yourself a LOT of time asking questions like these.  This is about as basic as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to create the actual list objects:

```
public List<Integer> parent = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public List<Boolean> black = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

if you don't do this, then your lists are null and access a property or method on someting which is not there produces a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 5):

So far, you've only created a reference, there's no underlying object.  Try the following:

```
public List<Integer> parent = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

`static` in `public static class` nested type declaration means that `Tree` objects can be created outside the context of the `RBTree` instance. Your errors have nothing to do with `static`: you get NPEs because your lists are not *initialized*. You can add initialization in the constructor of the `Tree`, or add an [initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).